# Compare two partitions of table in Hive

Tags: python, sql, hive, partition

I need to compare data changes in two partitions of table in Hive. Specifically, I have two partitions (ptn_dt='01-31-2019' and ptn_dt='02-28-2019'). Each partition contains the following columns - num_key and active_indicator (true or false).

I need to identify the following:

a. Count of NEW ENTRIES (num_key present in ptn_dt='02-28-2019' but nut in ptn_dt='01-31-2019'), with active_indicator='true'

b. Count of entries WITH CHANGE in active_indicator between months (num_key is present in both partitions, active_indicator is 'false' in ptn_dt='01-31-2019' and active_indicator is 'true' in ptn_dt='02-28-2019'

c. Count of entries WITH NO CHANGE in active_indicator between months (num_key is present in both partitions, active_indicator is 'true' in ptn_dt='01-31-2019' and active_indicator is 'true' in ptn_dt='02-28-2019'

So far, I was successful in getting the count per partition, grouped by active_indicator using the Hive SQL query below. However, I am having trouble when trying to compare in between partitions.

```
"""SELECT active_indicator,count(*) from table_name WHERE ptn_dt='2019-01-31' GROUP BY active_indicator"""
```

EDITED WITH SAMPLE DATA AND DESIRED RESULTS:

ptn_dt = '2019-01-31'

| num_key | active_indicator |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | true |
| 112 | false |
| 113 | false |
| 114 | false |
| 115 | true |
| 116 | true |

ptn_dt = '2019-02-28'

| num_key | active_indicator |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | true |
| 112 | false |
| 113 | true |
| 114 | true |
| 115 | true |
| 116 | true |
| 117 | true |
| 118 | false |
| 119 | true |

OUTPUT:

1. Count of NEW entries with active_indicator = 'true' = 2 (pertains to num_key 117 and 119)

2. Count of entries WITH CHANGE in active_indicator (false to true) between months - 2 (pertains to num_key 113 and 114

3. Count of entries WITH NO CHANGE in active_indicator (true to true) between months - 3 (pertains to num_key 111, 115 and 116

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hello. I just edited the post with some sample deta and desired results.

Comment: I tried the latest edit you shared, not sure, but it returned no values? :( Not sure if I missed something.

Comment: Help please. @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.  This puts the comparisons in the same row:

```
SELECT active_indicator,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ptn_dt = '2019-01-31' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN ptn_dt = '2019-02-28' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table_name
WHERE ptn_dt IN ('2019-01-31', '2019-02-28')
GROUP BY active_indicator;
```

Or, in different rows, you could use:

```
SELECT active_indicator, ptn_dt, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
WHERE ptn_dt IN ('2019-01-31', '2019-02-28')
GROUP BY active_indicator, ptn_dt;
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, use `lag()`.  For all combinations:

```
select prev_active_indicator, active_indicator, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(active_indicator) over (partition by num_key order by ptn_dt) as prev_active_indicator
      from table_name t
      where ptn_dt IN ('2019-01-31', '2019-02-28')
     ) t
where ptn_dt = '2019-02-28'
group by prev_active_indicator, active_indicator;
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried this but this just returns the count of the true and false per ptn_dt. How can I count the entries with changes in active_indicator (e.g. same num_key but active_indicator=false in January and active_indicator=true in February)? And also the count of those with no change in active indicator (both true for January and February)? And lastly, count of those NEW num_key (existing in February partition and not in January)?

Comment: Hello. I just edited the post with sample data and desired output.

Comment: I tried the latest edit you shared, not sure, but it returned no values? :( Not sure if I missed something

Comment: Hope the sample data and output made the question clearer.